# Priority queue that allows event cancelation

Tags: data-structures, priority-queue

I'm working on a real-time application centered around a priority queue, which has a twist: I need to support "cancelations" of any event sitting in the queue.

Obviously the traditional implementation of a priority queue, a heap, doesn't lend itself well to this application because locating an arbitrary item for deletion is O(n).

If you have a pointer to an item, though, deletion is only O(log n).  I figure I can do this by maintaining a hash table whose nodes are also linked together as a heap.  This should allow for O(log n) insertion, deletion, and pop-max.

Then again, how is that better than a binary search tree?  All operations there are also O(log n), so why maintain a cumbersome dual data structure?

It also seems to me like a skip list would be better overall; pop-max would be O(1), and other operations would be amortized O(log n).

And for some reason I keep coming back to the idea of a beap, which has O(sqrt n) performance for all operations.

I think any of these solutions would work, but my question is... Which would work best in a real-time system that strives to service requests with minimal latency?  Asymptotic analysis is useful, but big-O notation doesn't tell you how expensive an individual operation is.  My data set isn't huge -- a few thousand entries tops -- so although a binary search tree looks better on paper than a beap, the beap may very well outperform it in my case because it doesn't waste time with rebalancing operations.

Anyway, I was hoping someone had similar experiences here.  A priority queue with cancelation support doesn't seem to be well-described, but it doesn't seem to me like it's THAT far-out of a  problem that nobody else has implemented one before.

Comment: Do you have any idea what your mix of pop-max to cancellations is? Do you have 1% cancellations and 99% pop-max or any other mixture? That'll help you decide. Also, a lot of real-time applications are "heap sensitive"; is that true in this case?

Comment: I'm estimating the mix will likely be 50/50 (or close enough to not matter).  Cancelations won't be rare, that's for sure.  Also, what do you mean by heap-sensitive?

Comment: Most real-time systems I have worked on do not allow "heap allocation" after initialization; so data structures like a hash map which re-hashes after initialization are not allowed.

Comment: Oh, THAT heap.  I was thinking of heap, the data structure, since I had discussed it in my post.  My queue is unbounded, so heap allocation is unavoidable.  But there isn't tolerance for big operations like resizing a hash table.